# How to add browse file button to Windows Form using C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to select a file on the local hard disk when I click a "Browse" button.

I don't have any idea how to use the `OpenFileDialog` control. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 123, accepted):

These links explain it with examples

http://dotnetperls.com/openfiledialog

http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial67_Using-OpenFileDialog-to-open-files.html

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int size = -1;
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); // Show the dialog.
    if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
    {
       string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
       try
       {
          string text = File.ReadAllText(file);
          size = text.Length;
       }
       catch (IOException)
       {
       }
    }
    Console.WriteLine(size); // <-- Shows file size in debugging mode.
    Console.WriteLine(result); // <-- For debugging use.
}
```

Answer (score 53):

```
var FD = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
if (FD.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {
    string fileToOpen = FD.FileName;

    System.IO.FileInfo File = new System.IO.FileInfo(FD.FileName);

    //OR

    System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileToOpen);
    //etc
}
```

Answer (score 35):

```
OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
fdlg.Title = "C# Corner Open File Dialog" ;
fdlg.InitialDirectory = @"c:\" ;
fdlg.Filter = "All files (*.*)|*.*|All files (*.*)|*.*" ;
fdlg.FilterIndex = 2 ;
fdlg.RestoreDirectory = true ;
if(fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
textBox1.Text = fdlg.FileName ;
}
```

In this code you can put your address in a text box.

Comment: Upvote for the inclusion of the "Filter"!

Answer (score 1):

```
        int size = -1;
        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"YOUR FILE PATH";  
        DialogResult result = openFileDialog1.ShowDialog(); 
        // Show the dialog.
        openFileDialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;
        openFileDialog1.Title = "BROWSE TEXT BLT";
        openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        openFileDialog1.CheckFileExists = true;
        openFileDialog1.CheckPathExists = true;
        if (result == DialogResult.OK) // Test result.
        {
            string file = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            try
            {
                string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(file);
                size = text.Length;
            }
            catch (System.IO.IOException ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            TXT_FOLDER_PATH.Text = file;
         }
```