# How to choose where append data?

Tags: c#, winforms, streamwriter, system.io.file, folderbrowserdialog

I'm a begginer programmer and I'm learning C#, I have a big difficulty with Files. Someone can help me with this, please?

I created a .txt file and I want to append text choosing the file location instead creating/saving in the startup path just like my code does.

This is what I have:

```
public void btnGuardar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string caminho = Application.StartupPath + "ID_Cartões.txt";

        if (lblDEC.Text != "")
        {
            StreamWriter txt = File.AppendText(caminho);
            txt.WriteLine("ID: " + lblDEC.Text + "\r\n" + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss") + "\r\n");
            txt.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("Ficheiro guardado com sucesso!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hexadecimal não convertido.", "ERRO!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the `OpenFileDialog` as explained in this Q&A: [How to add browse file button to Windows Form using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4999734/how-to-add-browse-file-button-to-windows-form-using-c-sharp)

Comment: If you are starting out, I would highly recommend learning to use a serialization library like [json.net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json). This will likely simplify the process of storing and loading data from files or the network.

Comment: @JonasH how is json related to this question?

Comment: @Lei Yang, it is not, at least not directly. But whenever new programmers start with saving data they often go for StreamWriter or BinaryFormatter, and neither is great. A serialization library can greatly simplify the process of turning objects into data, and back again. But if you are new you might not be aware that such tools exist.

Answer (score 0):

Winforms has a [`SaveFileDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) control where the user can choose the location and file name or a [`FolderBrowserDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/controls/how-to-choose-folders-with-the-windows-forms-folderbrowserdialog-component?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8) control where they can choose a folder and you specify the filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an OpenFileDialog, the FileName property contains the file path of the file selected by the user.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{ 
  string filePath = openFileDialog.FileName; 
}
```

Comment: `using (var ofd = new OpenFileDialog()) { ... }` <- It's important that you dispose of it.